# Cox Proportional Hazards - Stratified vs non-stratified model for variable adjustment

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am testing for proportional hazards in my model.

#### Time-Dependent Model

```
cox.zph(coxph(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ age+anaemia+creatinine_phosphokinase+time:ejection_fraction+
                serum_sodium+time:serum_creatinine+hypertension, data=HF))

                           chisq df       p
age                       0.8322  1    0.36
anaemia                   0.9747  1    0.32
creatinine_phosphokinase  0.1540  1    0.69
serum_sodium              0.9080  1    0.34
hypertension              0.0604  1    0.81
time:ejection_fraction   54.5268  1 1.5e-13
time:serum_creatinine    29.9232  1 4.5e-08
GLOBAL                   79.2595  7 2.0e-14
```

I have p-values less than 0.05 for my variables above. Does that mean that I should simply discard my attempt to use time-dependent variables with my specific model?

#### Strata Model

```
cox.zph(coxph(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ age+anaemia+creatinine_phosphokinase+strata(ejection_fraction)+
                serum_sodium+serum_creatinine+hypertension, data=HF))

                          chisq df    p
age                      0.2148  1 0.64
anaemia                  0.4348  1 0.51
creatinine_phosphokinase 1.1017  1 0.29
serum_sodium             0.6291  1 0.43
serum_creatinine         0.0385  1 0.84
hypertension             0.3704  1 0.54
GLOBAL                   2.3858  6 0.88
```

**Is there any reason I should use the Time-Dependent model over the strata or vice-versa? How does stratifying affect my ability to interpret and present information?**

I know that I could graph the Schoenfeld test but I'd like to rely on this, only.

Comment: Your use of `time:covariate` interaction terms in the first model is wrong. That just sets up a single, time-constant extra variable representing the product of an individual's observation time with the covariate. Thus you get into a problem with causality: you are trying to use the fact of a long/short observation time to _predict_ whether survival is long or short. That method does NOT set up a time-varying covariate/coefficient, which is what I think you want. See the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf), especially Section 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strata adjustment method is a valid way to adjust for a covariate when the hazards of the variable you want to adjust for are not proportional over time. However, you will not get the beta coefficients for that variable. The strata method will have its own survival curves for each level of the covariate, and the curves will be similar to Kaplan-Meier curves.

Comment: Despite not getting a beta coefficient, can I still say that it is a statistically significant variable?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But you could do a univariate model using the KM method

Comment: Or you could try a log-likelihood ratio test to compare the models with and without the strata variable to see if the variable influence the model significantly.

Comment: Are you saying to perform the ratio test so I can determine if it is worth keeping the variable at all instead of stratifying it?

Comment: I am suggesting it as an indirect way to test the significance of the variable in your model

Comment: ```< 2.2e-16 *** ``` This is my p-value after the LRT. Does that mean that it's best to keep it unstratified?